# Laravel - Columns in the insert statement changes when trying to save data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on a Laravel project and I have an issue when trying to save data. Here is the error message that i get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into link_user_accounts (account_id, user_user_id, updated_at, created_at) values (1, 6, 2019-12-30 20:32:54, 2019-12-30 20:32:54))

I am expecting to see the following insert statement:

`insert into link_user_account(account_id, user_id) values(val1, val2)`

But in this case the `user_id` is somehow being renamed to `user_user_id`

**Models**

1. Account
2. User
3. LinkAccountUser

**UserController**:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $account_id = Auth::user()->account_id;

       $user = new User();

       $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
       $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
       $user->practice_number = $request->practice_number;
       $user->save();

       $user_account = new LinkUserAccount();
       $user_account->account_id = $account_id;

       $user->link_user_account()->save($user_account);
```

**User model relationship**

```
public function link_user_account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(LinkUserAccount::class);
}
```

**Account model relationship**

```
public function link_user_account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(LinkUserAccount::class);
}
```

**LinkUserAccount relationship**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'account_id', 'user_id');
}

public function account()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'account_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the **LinkUserAccount** model, remove the `user_id` for the other key:

```
public function user()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class); // It will automatically go to id on User
}
```

The way you had it, with `user_id` in the other key parameter, it was telling Laravel to look for `user_id` on the **User** model, instead of `id`, which in combination with the inclusion of the `account_id` as the FK and the slightly unusual naming convention (**LinkUserAccount**), probably confused it to the point of looking for `user_user_id`.

Comment: thanks for your response, I modified my code according to your suggestions as well as editing: protected $primaryKey back to "id' in the User model. I had it as protected $primaryKey = "user_id". It seem to be working for now.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful and fixed the issue.  Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the voting arrows on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Eloquent adds user_ to the id.
In my case I solved this by changing the primary key of my table simply by calling it 'id'